# Should USB controller drivers be updated?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

Should USB controller drivers be updated?

In Windows 7, many of the core system devices/buses/controllers still use stock Microsoft drivers dating back to 2006 -- things such as USB controllers and the PCI bus (and subsequent devices in the tree).

Should these be getting updated? I would think that surely there would have been improvements/fixes/updates to some or any of these drivers by now, now over 7 years old.

Does Windows know "best" in this case, updating these respective drivers when it's needed, or should the user be keeping an eye out for drivers in this "vein" of devices (meaning integrated/core/non-pluggable system devices that are built into the motherboard)?

Comment: If they work why change them?  The manufacture of the motherboard will supply any drivers required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If they work why change them?" - the most and frequent wrong way.

They can work but there can be security vulnerabilities which can allow a virus to get into your PC when you **just plug in** your device. And even best antiviruses **can't** catch them (or catch hardly). Most of USB driver updates are created to fix security bugs. So don't joke with it.
Update it.

Answer (score 0):

The way that USB communicates to every motherboard is different due to how the USB headers interact with the motherboards chipset.  So most likely the drivers have been updating "behind-the-scenes" with updates to the motherboard drivers.